# How to add quotes to dictionary keys with missing quotes in kafka messages

Tags: python, json

I'm consuming messages from kafka which are in byte format. But the quotes in the messages are missing and I need to process the key and value separately. When I try **"json.loads(msg.value().decode()"**, it throws error as below.

**What I have:**

```
# a short example of the message 
msg.value() = b'{time:"2022-10-23 06:55:00.000000 UTC",name:"NLU:G1H6J67 - SF, 6a, Zh. DE A", address:"11.11.11.11",address_name:null}'

value = msg.value().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(value)
```

Returns

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

****What I need:****

```
data = {"cal_timestamp_time":"2022-10-23 06:55:00.000000 UTC", "device_name":"NLU:G1H6J67 - SF, 6a, Zh. DE A", "device_ip_address":"11.11.11.11","subscriber_ip_address":null}
```

I've trid splitting after converting the byte to a string but  it requires too many manual work since there are 69 keys in the original data and many different types of values.

I've also tried eval() and ast.literal_eval(), then I get:

```
"SyntaxError: ':' expected after dictionary key"
```

Is there any way to do this convert easily and automatically in python ?

Comment: Removing Kafka tag since this is string parsing problem, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shown data isn't valid JSON. JSON keys also need quotes. E.g. `"time"` and `"name"`. Thus why any parser will fail.

---

If you cannot edit how the data is coming, then you will need to to first strip outer `{}`, then split on **unquoted** commas, **then** split on (also unquoted) colons to get key-value pairs.

Or, you can try regex to extract all matches `key:"quoted-value"` or `key:null`.

```
regex = r"([_a-z]+):(null|\"[^\"]*\")"
```

https://regex101.com/r/Z4TseB/1